# Ninject Factory Extension and Dealing with Memory Leak

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

This question is more of a "*how do I do it?*", rather than a "*what am I doing wrong?*". I have a class which is called **QueryProcessor** that processes queries (think CQRS). That object is injected into my presenters. The **QueryProcessor** needs to use the kernel to resolve bindings. Injecting the kernel in, either directly or via a factory, is easy. Doing so without causing a memory leak is the trick.

I have verified using a memory profiler that none of my **QueryProcessor** objects are being garbage collected. The class looks like this:

```
public sealed class QueryProcessor : IQueryProcessor, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IKernelFactory _container;
    private bool _disposed;

    public QueryProcessor(IKernelFactory container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    //[DebuggerStepThrough]
    public TResult Process<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));

        dynamic handler = _container.RetrieveKernel().Get(handlerType);

        return handler.Handle((dynamic)query);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !_disposed)
        {
            // dispose of stuff here
            _disposed = true;
        }            
    }
}

public interface IKernelFactory
{
    IKernel RetrieveKernel();
}
```

My composition root is reasonably straightforward. I am using the factory extension of Ninject.

```
public void OnLoad(IKernel kernel)
{
    //  Auto-Register all the validators which are stored in the Service assembly.
    AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssembly(_serviceAssembly).ForEach(
            result => kernel.Bind(result.InterfaceType, result.ValidatorType)
        );

    ManualRegistrations(kernel);

    kernel.Bind<IKernelFactory>().ToFactory();

    AutoRegisterType(kernel, typeof(IQueryHandler<,>));
    AutoRegisterType(kernel, typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
}
```

As mentioned, the injection is working, but it is leaving a memory leak. How am I supposed to get the Ninject kernel resolving stuff in my QueryProcessor without causing the leak?

Thanks

**Update - New Problem**

I tried to solve this problem by creating a new kernel with a new module, separate from the main kernel of the Composition Root. These sub-kernels would be created and disposed up, with their lifetimes being tied to that of the QueryProcessors. I hooked it up like this in the main module:

```
kernel.Bind<IQueryProcessor>().ToMethod(ctx => new QueryProcessor(new StandardKernel(new ProcessorModule(_serviceAssembly)))).InTransientScope();
```

It works fine before the kernel is disposed of for the first time. But after that, I get the following error message:

```
Error loading Ninject component ICache
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Suggestions:
  1) If you have created a custom subclass for KernelBase, ensure that you have properly
     implemented the AddComponents() method.
  2) Ensure that you have not removed the component from the container via a call to RemoveAll().
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
```

Damned if I do, damned if I don't ...

Comment: How do you bind the QueryProcessor? Who is disposing the query processor?

Comment: Also note that in case there is no memory pressure it's perfectly legal for the garbage collector *not to collect the objects*. Just waiting until you don't have a reference to an object anymore and then treating this as a memory leak is *not valid*. So what's your proof that there's actually a memory leak? Since you've used the the memory profiler please show us all of the paths to the GC root of a `QueryProcessor` (which should be collected but isn't).

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit The QueryProcessor is bound with kernel.bind<IQueryProcessor>.To<QueryProcessor>() and it is being disposed of by the Presenters in their respective Dispose methods. But, I can't dispose of the kernel, because it is needed elsewhere. Note, this is not a web project, so the kernel needs to live longer than a http request/response. I'll try and get some data from the profiler tonight. But it does have a button to force a GC and that button is effective for all other gen 1 objects which do disappear from the next memory snapshot after the GC.

Comment: with this configuration ninject does not hold keep a reference to `QueryProcessor`. If there's a memory leak it must either affect more types (for example there's something bound `InSingletonScope()` which holds on to `QueryProcessor`s) or the memory leak is because of some part of your code.

Comment: Sidenote: even with web applications it's not a good idea (performance-wise) to re-create the kernel for every requests. And while some people may still do it, there's certainly a lot who don't.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit That is interesting. Especially in light of the fact that the boilerplate  code that Nuget installs with Ninject is set up to re-create the kernel with every request.

Comment: @onefootswill - That makes sense. When dealing with *constrained construction* as in Windows forms or WebForms, one common solution is to treat each form like a separate application with its own composition root. This is often a better alternative to using a service locator or property injection.

Answer (score 0):

Since your application, not the DI container, is creating the instance it is also responsible for disposing the instance. This scenario can be handled by using the Register, Resolve, and Release pattern.

If you inject the kernel, then you have effectively implemented the [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). This means your application is explicitly dependent on your DI framework.

Rather than injecting the kernel, you should use an abstract factory as mentioned in the post [DI Friendly Framework](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/) to handle both creating and releasing the handler instances.

```
public interface IHandlerFactory
{
    dynamic Create(Type handlerType);

    void Release(dynamic handler);
}

public interface HandlerFactory
{
    private readonly Func<Type, dynamic> handlerMethod;

    public HandlerFactory(Func<Type, dynamic> handlerMethod)
    {
        if (handlerMethod == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handlerMethod");

        this.handlerMethod = handlerMethod;
    }

    public dynamic Create(Type handlerType)
    {
         return handlerMethod(handlerType);
    }

    public void Release(dynamic handler)
    {
        IDisposable disposable = handler as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
public sealed class QueryProcessor : IQueryProcessor
{
    private readonly IHandlerFactory handlerFactory;

    public QueryProcessor(IHandlerFactory handlerFactory)
    {
        if (handlerFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("handlerFactory");

        this.handlerFactory = handlerFactory;
    }

    //[DebuggerStepThrough]
    public TResult Process<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));

        dynamic handler = this.handlerFactory.Create(handlerType);
        try
        {
            return handler.Handle((dynamic)query);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.handlerFactory.Release(handler);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you use this approach, you are not requiring every handler to implement `IDisposable`, nor does your `QueryProcessor` unnecessarily need to implement `IDisposable`.

In your composition root, you just need to implement the handler method and register it as a parameter to your factory.

```
Func<Type, dynamic> handlerMethod = type => (dynamic)kernel.Resolve(type);
kernel.Bind<IHandlerFactory>().To<HandlerFactory>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("handlerMethod", handlerMethod);
```

Of course, if you are processing your handlers asynchronously you have to keep the instance alive until the end of the request rather than disposing it as soon as the `handler.Handle()` method returns. If that is the case, I suggest you analyze the [source code for WebApi](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) to work out what pattern is used to do that when dealing with the `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.

Comment: I should have mentioned, this is a Winforms application, not web. So, lifetimes are a little trickier. I am using the factory extensions, which you can see in my code. I don't know how to kill off the QueryProcessor without also killing off the kernel. I get I could give the QueryProcessor a Singleton lifetime. But that's probably not a ThreadSafe option.